# Replace words from dictionary with link using regex

Tags: c#, html, regex, richtext

So i have this html:

```
<img src="images" alt="alt" />
alt <a href ="http://google/something">alt</a>
test hallo world monkey
<p>alt</p>
```

and a dictionary containing

```
{alt, test, hallo, world, monkey, something}
```

so i need a regex or another method to replace words that are not within a A tag or a img tag
I have tryed the following regex:

```
(?<![a-zA-ZåøæÅØÆ])alt(?![a-zA-ZåøæÅØÆ])^*(?!=)$
```

http://rubular.com/r/p52ezGmVHO

Comment: Wouldn't this also replace the alt in your cool emoticon image too, since it has an 'alt' attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex and do a negative lookahead and lookbehind for letters:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])keyword(?![a-zA-Z])
```

in your example this would look like this:

```
bodyText = Regex.Replace(bodyText, "(?<![a-zA-Z])" + article.headword + "(?![a-zA-Z])", "<a class=\"dic\" href=\"#\">" + article.headword + "</a>");
```

My first intend was to do a positive search for whitespace characters, but then I thought of punctuation and stuff like this, a keyword is still a keyword if it has a .,!? at the end, right? So lookaheads and lookbehinds essentially check if something preceeding or succeeding your keyword, without replacing these, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i ended up doing

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<![a-zA-Z" + SpecialChars + "])" + article.headword + "(?![a-zA-Z" + SpecialChars + "])+(?!==)");

bodyText = regex.Replace(bodyText, "<a href=\"#dic\">" + headword + "</a>");
```

This will only replace the first one